# Proxy Problem while installing in anaconda

Tags: conda

```
ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? It looks to me like the error message is quite clear: "error in your proxy configuration". That's all anyone here will also be able to tell you from the error message. You should at provide your current settings so we might be able to tell you what is wrong with them. If you are in a corporate network, you should probably make a request with your IT department to tell you the correct proxy settings

Comment: How to rectify this error.